# Answer deleted as poor

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, answers, flags

I have previously flagged questions as "not an answer" when "not a real answer to this question" would have been more accurate and have been told, rightly I thought later, that the proper response was to downvote. However, today I found an [answer deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15674132/2548) and asked for clarification:

> I am not sure whether mine is a meta or flag question. I can see that
>   the question to which this is an answer is not suited to the current
>   SO, but I cannot see why this answer was deleted. It does not appear to violate any of the rules for answers. – 11 hours ago

The response was:

> declined - The answer does not actually answer the question asked; it
>   brushes the topic, without truly addressing it specifically.

So are bad answers now to be flagged for deletion?

Comment: Hrm, that one 'answer' is a little borderline. It is basically waffle, but it did try to answer, I guess.

Comment: The answer just explained a little about Access database, it does not answer the question and was rightfully deleted. Either "Not an answer" or "Very low quality" should be valid flags for such an answer.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd It used to be that bad or off topic answers were to be down voted, when I flagged them for deletion, that is what I was told. Is this a change of policy?

Comment: @Remou no policy I know of, but the flag option exist for a reason. Downvote is usually for well formatted answer which is just wrong or misleading, flag is for poor quality answer or something that doesn't answer the original question.

Comment: [Here is an example of an SQL Server answer to an MS Access question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894505/sql-return-value-for-every-thing-being-searched-in-select-command-even-if-rep/7894549#7894549), which means that the answer is of no use, no matter how good it is. Such answers are quite common, but not deleted, so it can get a little confusing.

Answer (score 4):

If it is an actual answer, a downvote is more appropriate.

But moderators have broad, discretionary powers, and if an answer clearly doesn't add any value, they will delete it.

Casting a flag requesting undeletion on an edge case like this one doesn't seem like a good use of anyone's time.  If the person posting the original answer really has something to say, and they can find a way to say it that is relevant to the question, they can always post another answer.

Comment: This could open up quite a large can of worms. There are quite a few repetitive or plain useless answers dotted around. Should they be flagged?

Comment: If you do flag them, don't use the "Not an Answer" option.  Cast a custom flag, and explain why you think the answer should be deleted.